# How to reformat a git project to "higher level" directories

Tags: git

I have a project called "client" which contains all the necessary files for the frontend, I created a git repository and committed all the changes during the UI/UX build, but then at the "client" directory level I created another one - "server", it is possible to make the directory data appear in the same git repository, because before that all the "client" files were there, and now two directories "client" and "server" should appear instead of them, if it is at all possible, then tell me any please how.
Sincerely, thank you)

**Below are the "client" and "server" folders:**

[image: 2 Folders]

**Below are the contents of the "client" folder:**

[image: Client Folder]

**Below are the contents of the "client" folder on GitHub:**

[image: Client Folder GIT]